# Why don't jQuery selector variables work within namespaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, javascript-namespaces

I am stumped on why this is not working. I'm looking to having more than one variable declared. What am I doing wrong?

```
     var message = (function ($) {
        var $modalBody = $('.modal-body'),
            $lblToUser = $modalBody.find('.to-user');
        return {
            toUser: function () {
                $lblToUser.val('To');
                $lblToUser.focus(function () {
                    if (this.value === 'To') this.value = '';
                    $(this).addClass('darker');
                }).blur(function () {
                    if (this.value === '') this.value = 'To';
                    $(this).removeClass('darker');
                });
            },
        };
    })(jQuery);

message.toUser();
```

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean?

Comment: It does not execute at all?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: And are there any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: Your code works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/7eb4U/

Comment: @user952851: Executes fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/eMSbe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a misplaced `,` at the end of `toUser` that may cause issues.

```
 var message = (function ($) {
    var $modalBody = $('.modal-body'),
        $lblToUser = $modalBody.find('.to-user');
    return {
        toUser: function () {
            $lblToUser.val('To');
            $lblToUser.focus(function () {
                if (this.value === 'To') this.value = '';
                $(this).addClass('darker');
            }).blur(function () {
                if (this.value === '') this.value = 'To';
                $(this).removeClass('darker');
            });
        }, // <-----
    };
})(jQuery);

message.toUser();
```

Comment: This still won't work on multiple correctly because it's selecting the same elements each time due to `var $modalBody = $('.modal-body'),$lblToUser = $modalBody.find('.to-user');`

Comment: My problem was adding "message.toUser()" within another namespace.

Comment: @user952851: So this answer's solution did not solve the problem? Why did you accept it then? This is just confusing. Don't select an answer just for the sake of it. You can provide your own answer after a given time and provide your solution, or flag to close the question, or delete it altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to initialize the document first?

```
$( document ).ready( function () {       // <-------
     var message = (function ($) {
        var $modalBody = $('.modal-body'),
            $lblToUser = $modalBody.find('.to-user');
        return {
            toUser: function () {
                $lblToUser.val('To');
                $lblToUser.focus(function () {
                    if (this.value === 'To') this.value = '';
                    $(this).addClass('darker');
                }).blur(function () {
                    if (this.value === '') this.value = 'To';
                    $(this).removeClass('darker');
                });
            },
        };
    })(jQuery);

    message.toUser();
});
```